# Replacing a constraint causes a crash of type NSGenericException

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, autolayout

I am trying to modify the multiplier of one of my constraints however it is not possible because it is a readonly property, so instead I am making a new constraint using the original and attempting to add it to a button:

```
 self.stashButtonTopConstraint.constant -= 3
 self.stashButton.removeConstraint(self.stashButtonConstraint)
 let newConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.stashButtonConstraint.firstItem, attribute: self.stashButtonConstraint.firstAttribute, relatedBy: self.stashButtonConstraint.relation, toItem: self.stashButtonConstraint.secondItem, attribute: self.stashButtonConstraint.secondAttribute, multiplier: 0.13, constant: 0)
 self.stashButton.addConstraint(newConstraint)
```

The crash occurs on the 4th line, and it says the following:

> The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint:
>      When added to a view, the
>   constraint's items must be descendants of that view (or the view
>   itself). This will crash if the constraint needs to be resolved before
>   The view hierarchy is assembled. Break on -[UIView
>   _viewHierarchyUnpreparedForConstraint:] to debug. 2015-07-19 02:21:04.507 Delightful[3224:85446] View hierarchy unprepared for
>   constraint.   Constraint: 
>     Container hierarchy:  >   View
>   not found in container hierarchy: >    That
>   view's superview: NO SUPERVIEW
>
> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Unable to install constraint on view.  Does the constraint
>   reference something from outside the subtree of the view?  That's
>   illegal. constraint:
>   view:>'

Comment: error message couldn't have been more descriptive. You should add constraint not to button, to its superview instead: `self.addConstraint(newConstraint)`

Comment: I tried that initially but it didn't work, just tried again and realized that the constraint ALSO needs to be removed from the superview. That got it working, thanks.